# when a pair of dice is rolled is the probability of getting a sum of 7 dependant on the number of trials?

Tags: probability

A pair of dice is rolled.We are interested in getting a sum of 7.

I want to know if this is dependent on the number of times the dice are rolled.

I also want to know whether if we roll it more number of times will the probability of getting a sum of 7 increase or decrease?

I tried researching Google but I was unable to find the answer.

Comment: what do you mean dependant on the number of times?

Comment: I mean the number of times the pair of dice are rolled like 10,20,30 times etc.

Comment: Okay, so say we're rolling the dice $30$ times. What precisely do you want the probability of? (Of rolling a $7$ in one of the $30$ rolls? Of getting a 7 on the next roll after that? ) If you specify this, then we can compare with if $n$ were $20$ or $40.$

Comment: I want the probability of getting a sum of 7 precisely.

Comment: You have missed my point that that is an ambiguous thing. I quoted two distinct interpretations of that phase. What is "getting a sum of seven"? I know what that must mean for a single dice roll, but not for $30.$

Comment: If you roll a dice $8$ times you are guaranteed not to get a sum of $7$.

Comment: So just consider the probabilities with 2,3,4,5, 6, and 7 rolls and see if the probabilities differ (they do)

Comment: I am sorry.If we roll the dice 30 times,I want the probability of getting a sum of 7 for all the 30 times.I also want the probability of getting a sum of 7 in the 30th roll.(where the 29 rolls produce a different sum).Hope this helps.

Comment: You roll $2$ dice, 30 times,  and you want the probability that all 30 trials result in a sum of 7. Is that what you're after?

Comment: Okay. Under the usual assumptions of fair dice / independent throws, the probability of rolling a $7$ all $n$ times decreases exponentially with $n$  (in fact it is $1/6^n$). The probability of getting a $7$ on the 30th roll is $1/6,$ regardless of what happened before.

Comment: To settle this interpretational issue say there are $n=3$ dice rolls. Are you interested in outcome $(7,7,7)$ or $(1,3,3)$ (where the latter is interesting since $1+3+3=7$? If it's the first, see my last comment... if it's the second see what Remy said a couple ago.

Comment: Thanks spaceisdarkgreen.I got my answer.

Comment: Was it the first thing he suggested?

Answer (score 1):

I have put a checkmark on the squares indicating that a sum of $7$ was obtained. This happens $6$ times out of $36$ possibilities.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6  \\ \hline
1 & &&&&&\checkmark\\ \hline
2 &&&&&\checkmark\\ \hline
3 & &&&\checkmark\\ \hline
4 & &&\checkmark \\ \hline
5 & &\checkmark\\ \hline
6 &  \checkmark\\ \hline
\end{array}

The probability that you get a sum of $7$ on one individual roll is $\frac{6}{36}=\frac{1}{6}$. By independence, the probability that you get a sum of $7$ on $30$ consecutive rolls of $2$ dice is

$${\frac{1}{6}^{30}} \approx 4.52\cdot 10^{-24} \text{ (almost impossible)}$$

The probability that you get a sum of $7$ on the $30$-th trial is independent on whether or not you got a sum of $7$ on the previous $29$ trials so it's just $\frac{1}{6}$